# AWS VPC and IP address of docker container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, subnet, vpc, aws-security-group

I have a docker container running  application-1  on an EC2 machine in a private subnet of my AWS VPC. I have another EC2 machine in the public subnet of my VPC running application-2.

Application-1 sends rpc command to application-2 and I have to whitelist  the ip address of application-1 in application-2. The problem is that I don't know what ip address to white list.

Thanks

Comment: Add security group of EC2 running with app1 into security group of EC2 running with app2.
No need to whitelist IP in this case, EC2 of app2 accept all request coming from ec2 of app1

Comment: I have already done that. The problem is that app-2 is designed to accept rpc commands only from localhost or exclusively whitelisted ip addresses. I have no control on app-2 and I have to make the whole system work.

Answer (score 1):

Consider changing your design to support private IP addresses within your VPC or subnet.

If that is not possible, then you need a discovery service. Look into Amazon ECS Service Discovery. This should provide what you need.

[Amazon ECS Service Discovery](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-ecs-service-discovery/)

Comment: I have both private and public subnet(with NAT gateway). I have configured the routing table so that all the local traffic stay within the VPC. The problem is that I have to explicitly whitelist app-1's ip address in my app-2.